# I try to make a discord.js bot and i got this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have an error when i run node . in the terminal

I try to run the bot with node . and i got this error.
I try to fix it but i can't.

Here is the code

```
const { Client, IntentsBitField } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent
    ],
})

client.on('ready', (c) => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'Hello') {
        message.reply('Hello World!')
    }
})

client.login(
    'my_token'
)
```

And here is the error

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
    at onConnectTimeout (C:\Users\biket\Desktop\discord-bot-gia-eshop\node_modules\undici\lib\core\connect.js:182:24)
    at C:\Users\biket\Desktop\discord-bot-gia-eshop\node_modules\undici\lib\core\connect.js:129:46
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\biket\Desktop\discord-bot-gia-eshop\node_modules\undici\lib\core\connect.js:168:33)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21) {
  code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Connection timeout means that your computer cannot reach Discord servers. This is most often a network problem and does not indicate an error in your program – in fact, the stack trace contains no references to your own code, meaning that an error in your code is unlikely the cause.

Check if you can connect to Discord, then run the bot again if you can connect:

```
$ ping discord.com
```

Answer (score -2):

this is an error for slow internet or network connectivity issue, i suggest you should use warp(1.1.1.1) and try it again.

Comment: WARP or 1.1.1.1 is not a fix to internet connectivity issues.